# MYSQL script doesn't run from command prompt but does from within mysql

Tags: mysql

Hi I have a script file that when I login to mysql from the command prompt and execute it runs no problem.
the command I issue is

```
\. test.sql
```

however from command prompt nothing happens

```
 -usa -p***** -h192.168.0.**** < test.sql
```

the script says which db to use and then issues a flush tables for export command for all the tables in the db.

I am happy with the syntax that executes from the command prompt as I have a test1.sql that is a simple select this works no problem.

I am on a windows 2008 R2 server and mysql 5.7.15

Comment: Do you get any output or errors ?
Have you tried specifying the full path to test.sql ?

Comment: no if I create an output file ie > output.txt it creates an empty file.  the full path makes no difference